# How to focus a v-btn after a dialog is opened?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to focus a [v-btn](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/buttons) after a [dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/dialogs) without activator is opened?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/53597532/1981247