# Programmatically set focus on button in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to focus the action buttons in a v-dialog every time it is opened. I tried using autofocus however it only works once.

Normally in Vuetify you can set the focus on an element by adding a reference and then calling the focus() function like this:

```
<v-text-field ref="refToElement" />
```

Code:

```
this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.refToElement.focus())
```

However for v-btn this doesn't seem to work. How can I use javascript to focus the v-btn every time the dialog is shown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuetify's autofocus works only on first modal open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472947/vuetifys-autofocus-works-only-on-first-modal-open)

Comment: @Traxo That question deals with v-text-field and unfortunately the code that works with v-text-field doesn't work with v-btn. That's one of the reasons I asked this question, because everything I found on the web had to do with focusing v-text-fields not v-btns. Maybe in a future version of Vuetify that will be fixed but for now the workaround is to add **$el**.focus().

Comment: I see, but I presume the solution you provided here would work in that question as well? Apparently OP accepted his own answer there, and was probably unaware of your (also my proposed) solution. I see I actually made a comment there basically same as your proposed solution here, so I think it should work.

Comment: Yeah I agree the accepted answer in that question is not very good. I actually tried it when I was troubleshooting and it did not work for me.

Comment: Ah you are right, for buttons we need to add `$el` apparently, and for text-field not. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQBzmN Perhaps you should let the OP know then. I am not sure if therein proposed solution with `v-if` is alright?

Answer (score 11):

For Vuetify 2.x use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.$refs.button.$el.focus()
})
```

Comment:  This worked for me! but `nextTick` didn't.

Comment: Same as @raevilman. What is wrong with `$nextTick`? Isn't it supposed to be exactly for this use case?

Answer (score 8):

To set the focus on a v-btn you can add **$el** after the reference. For example

```
this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.refToElement.$el.focus())
```

Full codepen of dialog and focused button: https://codepen.io/cby016/pen/eQXoBo.

**Edit:** For Vuetify 2.x try this

```
watch: {
  dialog () {
    if (!this.dialog) return
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.$refs.refToElement.$el.focus()
    })
  }
},
```

Comment: Works without `nextTick` as well

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Vuetify 2.x anymore: https://codepen.io/escapedcat/pen/qBEwBMY

Comment: My `v-text-field` was hidden with `v-if` and I needed the `nextTick` workaround, because the ref was undefined by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your elements dynamically make sure you use static ref for all the elements. I could not get the focus working because I was using dynamic ref like below:

```html
<v-text-field v-for="item in items" :ref="item.id"/>
```

When you use a static ref Vue will automatically index those for you and you can access them like so:

```html
<v-text-field v-for="item in items" ref="textField"/>
```

```js
const index = items.length - 1;

this.$refs.textField[index].focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version is (2.6.1)

possibly this will help you

```
  <b-text
    ref="username"
  />


  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$refs.username.$parent.$el['1'].focus();
    });
  },
```

Comment: not working, at least not in 2.6.7.  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')